# unir dos datos de un mismo campo en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Quiero realizar una consulta en MYSQL que me permita unir dos datos en un campo, el campo esta definido como un INT y estoy haciendo la consulta mediante un where in pero el problema es que me los muestra pero por aparte he utilizado varias funciones como `CONCAT` o `GROUP_CONCAT` pero ninguna resulta ser la correcta, aqui les dejo algunas capturas de pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi objetivo principal es que me muestre solo en la columna que dice granjas,
solo una fila donde este 1,2 solamente quiero eso, estaría agradecido si me ayduarán

aqui dejo el codigo de la consulta SQL

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(granja_id) AS total FROM formulario_precebo WHERE granja_id IN (1,2) GROUP BY granja_id
```

Comment: puedes añadir tambien la definición de la tabla que quieres consultar?  ten en cuenta que concat() se aplica a distintos campos DE UN MISMO REGISTRO, y tu quieres colocar valores DE DISTINTOS registros. Hay una posible solución para lo que quieres hacer

Comment: osea, mi objetivo es que solo me muestre una fila con solo los numeros 1 y 2, no 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 y 2,2,2,2,2,2,2 como se muestra en la imagen @Jakala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hice una prueba en [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), y me funcionó ok, pero eso sí, yo no usé el `GROUP BY` del final, ya que al colocarlo, me devolvió los resultados separados. Te sugiero probar sin ese `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(granja_id) AS total FROM formulario_precebo WHERE granja_id IN (1,2);
```

**EDITO:**

Este fue el ejercicio que hice en SQL Fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE prueba (campo1 TINYINT(3), campo2 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO prueba VALUES (1, 'Mesa'), (1, 'Silla'), (2, 'Estante'), (3, 'Cama');

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT campo1) AS total FROM prueba WHERE campo1 IN (1, 2);
```

Y Esto me retornó:

> total
>
> 1,2

Tal vez haya otros campos en tu tabla que impiden que la consulta funcione como quieres :/

Comment: hice la misma consulta que hiciste pero me sale `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,` y yo quiero que me salga `1,2` y no he podido resolver ese problema, si miras bien el pantallazo que deje yo no quiero eso que me sale en pantalla

Comment: Ah! De veras, leí en la documentación que además puedes usar `DISTINCT` dentro del `GROUP_CONCAT`, para evitar repetir valores iguales: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT granja_id)`

Comment: Edité mi respuesta.

Comment: agradezco mucho tu ayuda y quiero que me saques de una duda, también es posible que me muestre los dos promedios de las dos diferentes id

Comment: Y cuál sería según tú el promedio? No entiendo :o

Comment: la consulta completa que estoy haciendo es `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT granjas.nombre_granja) AS granjas,DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado,"%m"),"%M") AS mes, AVG(DISTINCT conversion_ajust_fin) AS total FROM formulario_precebo INNER JOIN granjas ON granjas.id = formulario_precebo.granja_id WHERE granja_id IN (1,2) AND año_destete = 2017 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado,"%m"),"%m")` el problema es que me toma los dos y los une, y quiero que me salgan asi parecido cuando me salen las id, aclaro el `DISTINCT` no me sirvio

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75002/discussion-between-quinqui-and-juan-esteban-yarce).